# Unversion a TortoiseHg repository

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am not an expert with version control systems, but I have a TortoiseHg (Mercurial) repository that I would like to unversion (remove it completely from version control), and possibly start a new version control history on it afterwards.

When I try to right-click a repository in an Explorer window, then under the "TortoiseHg" menu option there is no option to unversion or export the repository. I tried "Forget", but it just gives me the error message I describe in the next paragraph.

The reason that I want to remove the repository from version control is that TortoiseHg gives me an error message when I try to refresh the working folder. It says: "Failed to refresh", and lists a file with a "no match" message. I can't commit or merge with local etc. The repository has been untouched for half a year. I think I might have used an older version of TortoiseHg on it previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to "unversion" an entire repository just delete the `.hg` directory in the top level.  That will leave all your files untouched, but will remove every trace of Mercurial history.  Needless to say, this is not a reversible process.

Comment: That was easy. Thanks! When I created a new repository of the folder afterwards, the error message was gone.